# How to know if an app works in low-end device in Store?

Tags: apps, store, low-end-devices

When I'm browsing the Store in the Internet or in my Lumia 920 I can see and install all apps.

But sometimes I want to see games for my daughter's phone (Lumia 520) which only has 512MB RAM.

I know some apps can't be installed on this kind of phone but I don't know how can I see this info in the store (if an app needs at least 1GB RAM).

This question is applicable to the Web Store and the Store app in the phone.

**Edit**

A scenarios I want to cover is when someone with no Windows Phone want to change to a new phone but doesn't know if an specific app he want works in every kind of phone.

An example is a person who wants to leave iOS or Android and loves to play <s>Asphalt 8</s> *Temple Run 2*(which in this example works only in phones with +1GB RAM). So before buying a device he wants to check if this app will work on a Lumia 520 or if he needs to buy a Lumia 920 (for example)

Answer (score 3):

If you log into the store website with the account of your daughter's phone, you will only see apps that are available to it. If the account has both phones on it, you can toggle which phone you want to search with.

Comment: I can confirm this also. I have a Lumia 820 and 720. I searched for Fifa 13, which will work on the 820. When I switch to the 720 on WindowsPhone.com, I see this message "Your phone doesn't meet the minimum requirements needed to run this app.".

Comment: Yes @caschw, in my daughter's phone I can't find Temple Run 2. But I want to know this without her credentials (or phone).

Comment: Have you tried browsing the store on the website while logged in as her?

Comment: @caschw Sorry, missed your question. Yes, in this case it works but its far from perfect. Just realized that a way to know is to look after comments in ratings where people used a 512MB device. Not good too but manageable from me browsing the Store in my phone.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/apps/how-can-i-tell-if-an-app-has-requirements claims you can see requirements in the store by looking at the app's "details" screen.

From my desktop, I can see requirements listed at the left side of the screen.  For an example, see the Instagram app here: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/instagram-beta/3222a126-7f20-4273-ab4a-161120b21aea

Interestingly, none of the apps I've looked at detail the requirements explicitly.  For instance, http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/asphalt-8-airborne/3a9e6a13-433b-495d-879e-d4704fb40703 does not say anything about requiring 1GB ram.

Comment: Actually Asphalt 8 works in low-end devices. I has just guessed that not. I will update the post with another app.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. Asphalt 8 can be installed in 512MB phones. Just try Temple Run 2 instead.

Answer (score 1):

The Store app on the phone will not list search results that are incompatible with your phone. If you log into the web store with the account you use on the target phone, incompatible apps will be marked as such.

Comment: This is incorrect. The Store app in my experience DOES sometime list apps are not compatible with a phone.

Comment: @karancan Can you give me an example? I did a quick test with FIFA13 to verify before posting, but of course a single sample leaves room for error.

Comment: Skype on Lumia 610 at the time of last checking appeared in the Store but the phone did not meet the minimum requirements for the app to work

Comment: Sorry but I think I didn't make myself clear enough. You and @caschw did consider browse store with an account of a low-end device witch is a correct answer but the situation I meant was "I'm a iPhone user and want to know the requirements of an app". I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Just tested it and Temple Run 2 didn't show in my daughter's phone just searching but if I hit a deep link to it I can verify that I can't download in her derive. I just want to know this without her credentials or phone.